# Unit test for method block that will occur daily

Tags: unit-tests

I have a method **Fetch**, **GetExchangeRate** and method **FetchOnDemand**. *FetchOnDemand* checkds if *Fetch* is not called during one day it calls it.

*GetExchangeRate* calls *FetchOnDemand* first then does its particular job.

How can I test a *FetchOnDemand*.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how FetchOnDemand checks if Check has been called? Best scenario would be a code sniplet that shows how your components are structured... What inputs / outputs do you have?

Answer (score 5):

I assume you are asking how to test code that is time-dependent.

One strategy is to refactor the code under test so that you control the definition of the current time.  For example, in Java, instead of calling `System.currentTimeMillis()`, you might call a method on a "time provider" interface.  The default to implementation of that interface would call `System.currentTimeMillis()`.  For test purposes, you would use a test implementation that would return a time that  you would control.

Another strategy is to provide a way to override your reference time.  Suppose your code looks like this:

```
Fetch() {
    fetch something;
    lastFetchTime = current time;
}

FetchOnDemand() {
   if (lastFetchTime is at least a day ago) {
      Fetch();
   }
}
```

If you add a `SetLastFetchTime()` method, your test can control `lastFetchTime`.

Comment: and what about .NET?

Comment: Perhaps you could lookup the .NET API for getting the current system time.

Comment: Creating an interface for getting a time in module does not sounds good for me. Can you suggest anything else?

Comment: Done.  This isn't hard, but it still requires adding test hooks to the code under test.

Comment: I am building framework, I can't add methods like that.

Answer (score 3):

This is a great article on the subject that I've found very comprehensive and helpful. It's great for starting the conversation with your development team to make these sorts of things more test-friendly.

[Eradicating Non-Determinism in Tests](http://martinfowler.com/articles/nonDeterminism.html)

Comment: Very good article but unfortunately it did not helped me with my time issue because in .NET you cannot change a system time. Even more my tests should be running on Visual Studio Online, which won't let me to change its system time.